# Are test cases per requirements, per classes, or per methods?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

I'm starting to learn about Unit Testing. I know how to make unit tests, but I don't know what are the scopes of each tests. Same goes with Test Suites, and testMethods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into the following two book(s) if you are in java. Both the books will give you all intricacies that are required for better organizing your test(s) . Both the books are having a website which will give you fair idea about the book contents. Best of luck and be Test Infected ;)

1. [Growing object oriented software guided by tests](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/)
2. [xUnit Test Patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Organization.html)

Answer (score 2):

Tests for requirements are called *acceptance tests*. Usually you have some user story, which specifies requirement, and some scenarios which will check if requirement implemented correctly. So, you write acceptance test for each scenario.

Back to *unit testing*. Never stick to methods of class being tested, like `TestAddMoney`. Because tests are kind of live documentation, and they should describe what your class doing, not how. Ideally test should have descriptive names, which could be viewed by non-technical person. Thus write tests in terms of your class behavior, like `ShouldTransferMoneyToAnotherAccount`. This behavior-oriented tests are much more readable, and will not get obsolete if you rename `AddMoney` method to `InvestFunds`.

There is very nice [introduction to behavior-driven development by Dan North](http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/).